Debugging xtensor in VSCode
I am using CMake Tools to start the debugger  in VS Code. However, all of the containers from xtensor show up in this unreadable way.
I also cannot watch single elements by indices

Is there a way to make it more readable?
What I tried so far
I tried to use this launch configuration, too. The first setup command I got from this thread. With and without the first setup command, it behaves the same as described above
{
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "(gdb) new",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/myprogram",
            "args": [
                "--mode=ffa_sl",
                "--max-games=-1",
                "--chunk-size=100",
                "--chunk-count=100",
                "--log",
                "--file-prefix=./1K_simple",
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "python import sys; sys.path.append('/usr/share/gcc/python');sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/miniconda3/envs/pommer/bin/python');from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers;register_libstdcxx_printers(None)",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

